# ggarrange: Make plots (excluding titles, axis titles, axis labels) the same size

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm trying to recreate the style of `facet_grid` with individual plots and `ggarrange`. Using the height and width arguments of the `ggarrange` function allows me to make all the plots the same size but this includes the titles, axis titles etc. Is there a way to make the plots themselves the same size (other trial and error width the relative heights and widths)?

**Example**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))

p1 <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + theme(axis.title = element_text(size=100))
p2 <- p1 + xlab(NULL)
p3 <- p1 + ylab(NULL)
p4 <- p1 + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)

p <- ggarrange(p2, p4, p1, p3, nrow=2, ncol=2)

print(p)
```

This makes the following plot, where the top right plot appears larger than the others (although including the axis titles they're all the same size).

[image]

Something like this seems to get closer to the desired outcome:

```
p_fixed <- ggarrange(p2, p4, p1, p3, nrow=2, ncol=2,
                     heights = c(1, 1.3, 1, 1.3),
                     widths=c(1.1, 1, 1.1, 1))
```

[image]

Alternatively, the reason I'm doing this is because the colour scales on each chart need to be different, so if there's a way to do that using `facet_grid` that would help too. And a more general question could be what is the best way to replicate the `facet_grid` layout with individual plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution with `patchwork`. Set yur plots in a list and wrap into a composed plot using `wrap_plots()` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork)
#Data
df <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
#Plots
p1 <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + theme(axis.title = element_text(size=100))
p2 <- p1 + xlab(NULL)
p3 <- p1 + ylab(NULL)
p4 <- p1 + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)
#List
List <- list(p2,p4,p1,p3)
#Plot
Plot <- wrap_plots(List,ncol = 2,nrow = 2)
```

The output will be adjusted to keep same dimensions:

[image]